# What will happen if shared memory application works on distributed memory architecture?

Tags: c, operating-system, shared-memory, distributed-system

I've just started reading these memory model and is new to these shared memory model and distributed memory model.

I went through many documents for getting an idea about these. But, I still have some doubts:

1. What will happen if shared memory application works on distributed memory architecture?
2. What will happen if distributed memory application works on shared memory architecture?

Comment: Heard about `Distributed Shared Memory` ?

Comment: Maybe then it can give you idea on this .

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if shared memory application works on distributed
>   memory architecture?

Ans: For this to first happen you need caching. Out-process caching have locks and versions enabled in them therefore they are sort of safe and block calls from these simple applications.

> What will happen if distributed memory application works on shared memory architecture?

Ans: Havoc! Two application sharing one memory pool whereas they are expecting to be separate will bring to data inconsistency. Thats why you have locking. Just think of threads as an example (considering data is shared)